# How to forcefully fail the powershell script based on condition

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fail the powershell script if count of rows are less than 2 in a source file i.e. if file has only headers but no rows. but script is not getting failed. It's exiting without fail.

```
$Length = Get-Content "C:\Users\TestFile.csv" | Measure-Object -Line

$count = $Length.Count

If ($count -lt 2)
{
    return 1  --( Looking to fail when count is less than 2)
}
else
{
    return 0
}
```

Comment: `$count = $Length.Lines` or `$Length = (Get-Content "C:\Users\TestFile.csv" | Measure-Object -Line).Lines`

Comment: Guessing you mean `throw "error here"` when `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that's correct understanding , wanted to fail the script as if error has occured.

Comment: @Theo I am applying the solution and will let forum know in 2-3 days, sorry was out due to sick,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Content "C:\Users\TestFile.csv" | Measure-Object -Line` returns an **object** with these properties: `Lines, Words, Characters, Property`

What you are after is the `Lines` property, so either do

```
$count = (Get-Content "C:\Users\TestFile.csv" | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
if ($count -lt 2) { exit 1 }
```

or

```
$count = Get-Content "C:\Users\TestFile.csv" | Measure-Object -Line
if ($count.Lines -lt 2) { exit 1 }
```

---

Your question says you want to *"to fail the powershell script if count of rows are less than 2"*, so that would mean you want to **exit** the script if such is the case with an exitcode of 1 (as in your own code).
If using exit is too harsh, then you can do

```
if ($count -lt 2) { throw "The file has less than two lines" }
```

which will throw an exception message and stop further execution of the script, but will not exit powershell itself.

or

```
if ($count -lt 2) { Write-Error "The file has less than two lines" }
```

which will show an error message, but will also continue the script.

If this is part of a **function**, then you could do

```
if ($count -lt 2) { Write-Error "The file has less than two lines"; return 1 }  # not 0 for error; 0 for success
```

Comment: When i run the script it just does nothing like failure message. Does that mean it has got failed or terminated when writing exit 1

Comment: Is there a downside by just writing exit 1 inside IF and exit 0 in ELSE i.e. I am Expecting powershell will shut down and stop to execute.. is that correct understanding.

Comment: @Goks It all depends on what you want the script to do. `exit 1` will exit powershell, so if you run the script from some other software or code that does something with that exitcode it's fine. However, if you want your powershell session (remaining script) to handle the fail you should not use `exit`, but return a value of failure instead, so the rest of the script can deal with that and carry on. There is no absolute way of doing this, it all depends on how to detect and handle errors (or not) in the rest of the script. Just try out the various options I gave.

Comment: Yes I am executing the powershell command from Informatica ETL ( which is installed in Windows Server ) . So executing from Informatica Command Task : powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command "$PMRootDir\Folder\PMCMD\Testfile.ps1 $$inputfile $$Header_rows $$Logfile"  which in turns calls the command task to call execute the powershell script Testfile.ps1 .. Once Exit 1 is executed it will fail the workflow come out of powershell and command task.